How to create videos with Hebrew text in Manim?
I am trying to create a video in Manim that includes Hebrew text. I have been using XeLaTeX as the LaTeX compiler because of its Unicode support. However, I am encountering issues with text rendering and LaTeX compilation errors. I've tried using the polyglossia package to handle multiple languages, but I keep getting errors related to the Hebrew text.
Here's a snippet of my code:
from manim import *

class MyScene(Scene):
    def construct(self):
        tex_template = TexTemplate()
        tex_template.tex_compiler = 'xelatex'
        tex_template.output_format = '.pdf'
        tex_template.preamble = r"""
        \usepackage{fontspec}
        \usepackage{polyglossia}
        \setmainlanguage{english}
        \setotherlanguage{hebrew}
        \newfontfamily\hebrewfont{Arial}  % Используйте шрифт поддерживающий иврит
        """

        comment = Tex(r"\textenglish{Hello} \texthebrew{שלום}", tex_template=tex_template)
        comment.to_edge(DOWN)
        self.play(Write(comment))
        self.wait(1)
 

Error:
[04/13/24 22:24:10] ERROR
LaTeX compilation error:
tex_file_writing.py:312 
Undefined control sequence.


It's not clear which one is line 312. PS: While you wait for someone to answer, are there any useful ideas from research?

class MyScene(Scene):
def construct(self):
    rus_heb_template = TexTemplate(tex_compiler="xelatex", output_format='.xdv')
    rus_heb_template.add_to_preamble(r"\usepackage{fontspec}")
    rus_heb_template.add_to_preamble(r"\usepackage{polyglossia}")
    rus_heb_template.add_to_preamble(r"\setdefaultlanguage{english}")
    rus_heb_template.add_to_preamble(r"\setotherlanguages{russian,hebrew}")
    rus_heb_template.add_to_preamble(r"\newfontfamily\russianfont{Times New Roman}[Script=Cyrillic, Language=Russian]")
    rus_heb_template.add_to_preamble(r"\newfontfamily\hebrewfont{Arial}[Script=Hebrew, Language=Hebrew]")

    solution = Tex(r"""
        \begin{russian}
            Кириллица
        \end{russian}
        \begin{hebrew}
        שלום
        \end{hebrew}
        $\frac{1}{2}$
        """, tex_template=rus_heb_template)
    self.play(Write(solution))
    self.wait(2)


As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
