Creating table in manim with unicode characters
I want to create a table in manim and write persian alphabet in its cells, but the table doesn't get created, i can create a table with the exact same code only passing it english alphabet. So i know the problem is that it can't show unicode. The same thing would apply about text but then i would use font="Arial", and the problem would go away.
a=Text("سلام",font="Arial")
i wanted to see if there is something similar for the table as well.i create a table with the following code:
T1=Table(mylist)
self.play(Write(t1))
mylist is the list containing the persian alphabet, and in general in manim no unicode character(non-ascii) could be shown.
To solve this problem, i tried to provide the attribute-value font="Arial" in the Table definition, but i get the error that there isn't such a property.

Maybe this could help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78321796/how-to-create-videos-with-hebrew-text-in-manim Manim uses a tex template internaly. Perhaps you need to add a package there.
